# Serialize object with special characters to xml

Tags: .net, xml, serialization

I got an object which has some properties. One of the properties contains a pipe ('|') character and a Null Character (character 0).

When I Serialize to xml, the Null character is converted to &#x0 but not the Pipe Character.

The Pipe character is causing an exception when Deserialize.

```
<THPayment>Test | &#x0; with invalid characters!</THPayment>
```

Any ideas please?

JP

Comment: Post the actual code and the actual exception, as returned by `Exception.ToString()`. You don't even mention which classes you use for serialization and deserialization

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was not caused by the Pipe character. Although the serialize converts Chr(0) to &#x0, when you try to load the xml into an xElement, it will throw an error stating that it contains an invalid character (chr(0)).

I will need to make that property XMLIgnore and another shadowing serializable property that converts this property to Base64 and back.